# How to merge /boot partition into root partition

Tags: partition, grub

I'm trying to remove the dedicated `/boot` partition and merge it into root partition `/`.
I found https://askubuntu.com/questions/741672/how-do-i-merge-my-boot-partition-to-be-a-part-of-the-partition already, but that doesn't seem to help.

What's the situation:

```
# uname -a
Linux c02 6.1.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.52-1 (2023-09-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 4 TiB, 4398046511104 bytes, 8589934592 sectors
Disk model: QEMU HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1673AA12-2A54-4718-AF1E-58FE670A87E3

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2      4096    2007039    2002944  978M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   2007040   10008575    8001536  3.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda4  10008576 8589932543 8579923968    4T Linux filesystem
```

The following works and let me reboot the machine successfully:

```
# copy content of boot partition to root
cp -a /boot /boot.bak
umount /boot
rm -rf /boot
mv /boot.bak /boot

# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-12-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-12-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-10-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-10-amd64
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
done
```

But when deleting the physical boot partition additionally, reboot fails:

```
# fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.38.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

This disk is currently in use - repartitioning is probably a bad idea.
It's recommended to umount all file systems, and swapoff all swap
partitions on this disk.


Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-4, default 4): 2

Partition 2 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.
```

Which results in a grub error:

```
error: no such partition.
grub rescue>
```

When re-installing `grub` via `apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc` I get the following grub error then:

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk `hd0`.
grub rescue>
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you also check fstab to remove the mount of the now missing /boot partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update-grub` will actually only update the GRUB *configuration file* at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

The GRUB core image (which is mostly within your BIOS boot partition) contains a partition number and a pathname. Those tell GRUB how to find the `/boot/grub` directory, and thus the GRUB configuration file and the GRUB modules like `normal.mod`.

Unmounting the `/boot` partition had no effect on GRUB, as GRUB does its job before the Linux kernel even starts. Since you did not update the information encoded into the GRUB core image (by re-running `grub-install /dev/sda` after unmounting the old `/boot` filesystem and moving `/boot.bak` in its place), GRUB simply kept using the old `/boot` partition until you removed it. If you had made any changes to the GRUB configuration before running `update-grub` in your procedure, you would have noticed that the changes did not actually take effect.

So, the thing to do after `mv /boot.bak /boot` should not be `update-grub`, but:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

You achieved effectively the same by running `apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc`. But now the error message is `attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'`. That tells me GRUB is using BIOS routines to access the disk, and apparently QEMU's BIOS emulation routines have not been updated to handle >2TB disks, so you are hitting the 2 TB limit.

(And yes, I've analyzed a vanilla Debian 12 `grub-pc` installation. The only modules embedded within the GRUB core image in a simple installation like this are `fshelp.mod`, the appropriate filesystem driver module (e.g. `ext2.mod)`, the appropriate partition table type module (e.g. `part_msdos.mod` or `part_gpt.mod`) and the `biosdisk.mod`. Although there would be a BIOS-independent `ahci.mod` or `ata.mod` available, *they are not used by the default installation.*)

Unfortunately, when your root filesystem is sized at ~4 TB, you really should switch to booting in UEFI mode. To do that with Debian's QEMU (without Secure Boot support), you'll need to have the `ovmf` package installed, and to change the `<os>` section of your VM's XML configuration file to something like:

```
<os>
  <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-5.2'>hvm</type>
  <loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.fd</loader>
  <nvram template='/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS_4M.fd'>/wherever/you/keep/your/VMs/vmname.nvram.fd</nvram>
  <boot dev='hd'/>
</os>
```

Then you could

1. reuse the space of your BIOS boot and former `/boot` partitions to create an EFI System Partition,
2. add a `/etc/fstab` line to mount it to `/boot/efi`,
3. replace `grub-pc` and `grub-pc-bin` packages with `grub-efi-amd64` and `grub-efi-amd64-bin`,
4. run `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --force-extra-removable /dev/sda`

and once successfully booted in UEFI mode, run `grub-install /dev/sda` again to ensure the UEFI NVRAM boot variable is set correctly. Then install and learn to use `efibootmgr` to manage your boot settings from within a running OS in a standardized way.

If you are not yet running in UEFI mode when running `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi`, the `--force-extra-removable` will install a second copy of the UEFI GRUB at `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi`: the removable media/fallback location.

In case you want Secure Boot too, replace `OVMF_CODE_4M.fd` with `OVMF_CODE_4M.ms.fd` and the NVRAM template `OVMF_VARS_4M.fd` with `OVMF_VARS_4M.ms.fd`. Add the `grub-efi-amd64-signed` and `shim-signed` packages, and re-run `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --force-extra-removable /dev/sda`.

Comment: The result is the same as reinstalling grub (see my edited post). Even when running `grub-install /dev/sda` I get a success message from `grub`. But reboot fails with `error: attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0.`

Comment: See my edit above. The short of it is that your VM's current BIOS seems to be incapable of handling disks greater than 2 TB. Either keep using a separate `/boot` filesystem that must be located completely within the first 2 TB of the disk, or switch to UEFI boot (with or without Secure Boot) as outlined in my edit.

Comment: I agree, that keeping `/boot` will lead to less trouble. I'll go with that suggestion. Thanks.